# How to show span class inside the textbox?

Tags: html, css

I have calendar option to select the date. The calendar icon showing in outside of text-box.

```
<div class="input-prepend">
<input class="span12"  type="text"  readonly="readonly" id="date" name="date" placeholder="dd-mm-yyyy" />
<span class="add-on"><i class="icon-calendar"></i></span>
</div>
```

How to show icon span in inside text-box using CSS?
Thanks

Comment: Make position of element with class **add-on** as relative and then apply **left** and **top** css

Answer (score 3, accepted):

make a box/div looking like input box and put calendar icon to left

and insert a input element without border

```
input{
  border: 0 solid #fff !important;
}
```

> Note: use calendar icon in label so when user click on icon it gets focus to input tag

see the example at [go to input box in stay in touch](http://www.app4pc.com/)

Answer (score 1):

```
.input-prepend {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
}

.add-on {
    position: absolute;
    right: 5px;
    top: 5px;
}
```